# Android: Swipe in ViewPager too quick that the page is not completely loaded

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a problem with the ViewPager. Here is a snipet of my code:

```
myViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          if (position == 3) {
             // Load some content in page using LiveData
             page3vm.getIsPageActif().setValue(true);
          }
        }
    ...
    });
```

And in the third page, I use observer to load some content:

```
public class Page3Fragment extends Fragment implements LifecycleOwner {
...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    vm.getIsPageActif().observe(this, this::updateUIAndLoadSomeContent);
}
```

The problem is, when I swipe to page 3 too quickly, the method **updateUIAndLoadSomeContent** is not called. When I swipe slowly there is no problem.

What is the better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `onResume` function in the `Page3Fragment` do?

Comment: @Reaz Murshed I didn't implement the onResume, why ?

Comment: Can you please put `vm.getIsPageActif().observe(this, this::updateUIAndLoadSomeContent);` inside your `onResume` function and check?